# Redirecting to VF Page from Managed Package UI

Tags: visualforce, javascript, angularjs

I want to redirect user to a VF Page from a managed Package UI where code is written in Angular JS,

```
<div class="slds-no-flex">
    <span><button class="slds-button slds-button" onclick="redirectToMap();" id="Btn" value="{{a.id}}">View Map</button></span>
```

JS

```
 function redirectToMap() {

sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(openSubtab);
sforce.console.getFocusedSubtabId(closeSubtab);


}

var closeSubtab = function closeSubtab(result) {

var tabId = result.id;
sforce.console.closeTab(tabId);

  };

var openSubtab = function openSubtab(result) {

var parentID = document.getElementById("Btn").value;
var primaryTabId = result.id;
sforce.console.openSubtab(primaryTabId ,'/apex/AccountDisplayVF?id=' + parentID, 
true, 'New Map', null);
};
```

This isn't working . Anything I am missing?

Comment: have you tried '/apex/c__AccountDisplayVF' (assuming that page is unmanaged)?

Comment: Are you in the console UI? The code you posted looks like it would only work there.

Comment: I'll write up a brief answer for posterity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that when you're opening an unmanaged page from a Managed package, the platform is assuming the namespace of the managed package should also prefix your Visualforce page.

So, for example, if you have a Visualforce page in the `NS` namespace, and then put a button on that page that navigates to an unmanaged page, the platform would assume that you wanted `NS__MyPage` instead of just `MyPage`. To prevent this, you can qualify your Page with the local (`c`) namespace, so in your case:

```
/apex/c__AccountDisplayVF
```

Answer (score 5):

Always use [`$Page`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_page.htm) global variable for redirection in a visualforce page.

`$Page.PageName` if its outside namespace.

or `$Page.Namespace__PageName`, if its inside.

---

For accessing $Page in JavaScript placed inside a static resource, use:

1. a global variable
2. some design pattern to avoid a global variable as mention in [this blog](http://forcetrekker.blogspot.nl/2016/05/move-javascript-code-from-visualforce-to-static-resources.html).